# Convert LaTeX to String that can be evaluated (by MathJS)

Tags: javascript, latex, mathjs

Say I have the following LaTeX code

```
\frac{5+5}{\left (3+2  \right )*1}
```

[image]

is there a JS module that allows me to convert this code into a plain text string like

```
( 5+5 ) / ( (3+2) * 1 )
```

(this string can be evaluated by MathJS - which the LaTeX code can't)

Comment: did you end up finding a soluting for this?

Comment: No, sorry haven't looked at it since...

Comment: did you found any solution for this

Comment: @Abid I didn't at the time and haven't been looking the last 3 years